# Posting variables to a php file and opening it in new window, without using forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am doing a small php project. In this I have one page, which gets values from MySql and display it in HTML tables. Now there is generate pdf button,which generates PDF using MPDF in another php script.  I need to send HTML table source code to the page containing php script to convert it into a pdf. I have used the below code to do this.

```
var html= $("#tblExport").html();
window.open('pdf.php?html='+html, '_blank', 'scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,fullscreen=yes,status=no');
```

Problem of above code is that, it is using GET and hence cannot send large string values to other php file. 
I have tried to do this post using below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btnExportpdf").click(function(){
       var html= $("#tblExport").html();
       $.ajax({ 
          type: "POST",            // Methode POST or GET
           url: "pdf.php",        // PHP file to processing the data
           data: { "html": html }  // post variables that will handetover to php
       })
       .done(function( msg ) {     // response
          console.log(msg)         // data retuned from php
        });
    });
    });
```

Now I am stuck here. I am able to POST parameters, but how to open the php file,to which parameters are posted in a new window.

So the issue is that I want to open a new window with PDF of HTML table, on click of generate PDF button.
Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: check on the php side (your `some.php`) and extract the `$_POST`. Most likely `$_POST['html']` has it and just output it thru PHP

Comment: How to open pdf.php in new window first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use a form or JS.

Here is the form method.
http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_form_target.asp

```
<form id="pdf_form" action="pdf.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input id="pdf_html" type="hidden" name="html" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Get PDF">
</form>
```

jQuery - you still need the form above, but the submit button may be hidden or removed.

```
$("#btnExportpdf").click(function(){
    var html= $("#tblExport").html();
    $("#pdf_html").val(html);
    $("#pdf_form").submit();
});
```